# Developing CocoaPods - requires cleaning (CMD+K) to see the changes

Tags: xcode, cocoapods, xcode10, incremental-build, xcode10.2

I develop a library distributed with CocoaPods.
The library has an example project which I also use to develop and test new features.

The workflow is as follows:

1. Edit the source file
2. Run the project
3. See the changes

**The problem is that I cannot see any changes unless I clean the project first (cmd+K)**

So, to make it work, I have to resort to the following workaround:

1. Edit the source file
2. **Clean the project (CMD+K)**
3. Run the project
4. See the changes

How could I avoid doing step 2 all the time, as it slows down my development speed significantly?

I haven't faced this issue with older versions of Xcode or CocoaPods, however, I don't remember which ones specifically.

[Library I'm developing](https://github.com/richardtop/CalendarKit)

[CalendarKit.podspec](https://github.com/richardtop/CalendarKit/blob/master/CalendarKit.podspec) file

[Demo project structure with the Podfile](https://github.com/richardtop/CalendarKit/tree/master/CalendarKitDemo)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It's a known issue with Xcode "new build system".

Switching to the "Legacy Build System" resolves the issue.

[Source](https://github.com/CocoaPods/CocoaPods/issues/8073)